# Corona - Create a drop down list

Tags: drop-down-menu, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to create a drop list in Corona, something like:

- Task 1

  - Sub Task 1.1

    - Sub-sub task 1.1.1
  - Sub Task 1.2
- Task 2

  - Sub Task 2.1

I'd like the list to expand or collapse when clicked for it's appropriate child items, if possible.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Corona is for creating mobile apps where tree views are difficult to use. See [Tree View for Mobile Devices](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5709/tree-view-for-mobile-devices), and consider a drill down with [Corona Table views](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newTableView.html) if you need to nest more than a single level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at Widget Candy from X-Pressive, I use it in my apps, it's great

```
http://www.x-pressive.com/WidgetCandy_Corona/
```